# Azure Mobile using Existing Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

For an Azure mobile app to be able to transfer DTO's from their mobile SDK to their backend SDK, they need to inherit the EntityData class that has some necessary properties, for some features like offline sync.
When you need to use an existing database in your mobile app you need to make some changes to it, adding the necessary columns that Azure require, like on this tutorial in this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-use-existing-sql-database/

Im following  it, but its not working.
I have an initializer that runs when I change my model, and create some Identity users. Those users have a relation with a entity that I added the EntityData properties like the guide said to. But everytime the initializer kicks in I get a NULL exception to the CreatedAt field saying it cant be inserted with null value. Even it having the proper annotations to mark it as database generated.
I tryed to do "CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.Now();" in the initializer but didn't work either.

Here's the initializer code:

```
public class EqcDbInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ContextoEQC>
{
    protected override void Seed(ContextoEQC context)
    {

     if (!contexto.Roles.Any())
         .
         .
         .
         .
        var usuarioRestaurante = new Usuario
        {
            DataCadastro = new DateTime(2014, 10, 12),
            Email = "gerente@restaurante.com.br",
            UserName = "gerente@restaurante.com.br",
            Endereco = new Endereco {
              Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(); //Here dosent matter if I fill
              CreatedAt = DateTimeOffset.Now; //those two or not, same exepction always.
              Bairro = bairro;
              Cep = cep,
              Cidade = cidade,
              Estado = estado,
              Logradouro = logradouro,
              Numero = numero,
              Pais = pais,
           }
        };
        userManager.Create(usuarioRestaurante, "12345678");
        userManager.AddToRole(usuarioRestaurante.Id, "Restaurante");
}
```

The Enyity Code:

```
public class Endereco
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Deleted)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }

    [Index]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
    [MaxLength(36)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.UpdatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Version)]
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int UsuarioId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    //Navegação
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have some annotations on your entity class that are conflicting with the annotations that the Mobile Apps SDK expects. You should remove your annotations and keep only `TableColumn`:

```
[TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]
public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

[TableColumn(TableColumnType.Deleted)]
public bool Deleted { get; set; }

[TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
[MaxLength(36)]
public string Id { get; set; }

[TableColumn(TableColumnType.UpdatedAt)]
public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

[TableColumn(TableColumnType.Version)]
public byte[] Version { get; set; }
```

Try changing your DTO and then re-run the database initializer. If you have a custom initializer, make sure the Mobile Apps one runs by setting it in your migration configuration (see [How to make data model changes to a .NET backend mobile service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-code-first-migrations/#using-code-first-migrations-without-an-initializer)):

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new EntityTableSqlGenerator());
}
```

Comment: ATM I have no real data on my DB and so far I havent enabled migrations. Is there another way to set the SQLGenerator to the Mobile One?
So far from the day I posted this question I have rewriten my entity classes to inherit from EntityData and adapted my current Web API to be mobile ready like in this guide(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#install-sdk). I have no more issues with CreatedAt but with Id now. When initializer trys to save the enittys it says "Id field is required". Do I need to manually set it?

Comment: Also, a very interesting point. I started this project as a Angular SPA with a web API backend for data access. For authentication im using ASP Identity and so my context inheris from IdentityDbContext<> typed with my User class that inherits from IdentityUser. In my User class I added those EntityData properties(except the Id one).
I havent found anything about working with Identity and Mobile Apps.
Maybe Identity dosent work well with the Mobile App?

Comment: The ID should be set by the EntityDomainManager when you go to save the item. Where do you get the exception?

Comment: I get it in my seed method from the DropCreateAlways initializer.

Comment: About the DomainManager. I see TableControllers need them on the constructor. This is when you say it will fill the Id, when the controllers actions are invoked and actually do some CRUD?

Comment: Try extending EntityData and remove all of the system properties from your data type. You probably have a duplicate ID property, or an ID with the wrong annotation.

Comment: I did this and I got passed the CreatedAt problem. Made all my entities inherit from EntityData and made my current Web API mobile ready just like in the Azure Docs guide I mentioned earlier. Then this Id problem poped up. Now I see that the initializer in the basic Azure Mobile App you download form Azure Portal also fills the Id with a new Guid. Gonna do that on my Initializer and see where I get.